# Micronaut AuthenticationProvider is not called

Tags: micronaut

I want to add a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to [micronaut-security as described in the docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/index.html#custom). But my custom implementation is never called:

**Controller:**

```
@Get("/team")
@Secured(SecurityRule.IS_AUTHENTICATED)
HttpResponse getTeam(@Body @Valid JoinTeamRequest req) {
    log.info("Get own team")
    return HttpResponse.ok()
}
```

**Custom AuthenticationProvider**

```
@Singleton
class LiquidoAuthenticationProvider  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    LiquidoAuthenticationProvider() {
        println "============= INIT LiquidoAuthenticationProvider"  // this gets called. Can set a breakpoint on it
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, AuthenticationRequest<?, ?> authenticationRequest) {
        println "============= authenticate "    // <=== this never gets called. Breakpoint is never reached ?????????? Why?

        [...] some code to authenticate request that returns flowable UserDetails on succcess [...]

    }
}
```

Why is the authenticate method never called?

Some more info that might be relevant:

- I am using micronaut in the backend.
- micronaut.security.authentication-provider-strategy: ANY  (leaft as the default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:  `AuthenticationProviders` in Micronaut are only called, when the request acutally contains an `Authorization` Header. Actually a nice performance improvement. But one needs to know. Can be misleading when debugging.

Comment: So basically it is impossible to implement an AuthenticationProvider that uses a different header?

Comment: If you need to have special handling for your specific HTTP header, I suggest you have a look at filters. There you can handle any request data (header, method, body, url, query parameters etc.)